# Don't see certain assemblies in the GAC

Tags: asp.net, gac

I am using 3rd party controls in my asp.net project. These controls are supposed to be installed in the GAC but when I run gacutil -l I don't see them listed, but when i look at

C:\windows\assembly

The files are there. (I ran gacutil from this directory, if that makes a difference).

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that the gacutil -l isn't showing them, how are you reviewing the output? Generally that spits out alot, pipe it to a text file if you aren't already

```
gacutil -l > gac.txt
```

makes it tons easier to review/search

What third party controls are we talking about? Can you give a name?

Comment: I was eyeballing the list in the "dos" ouput. What dir does the file get put into?

I am using infragistics controls.

Comment: too much to eyeball, trust me...the txt file should be in the directory you are running gacutil from..or you can add a path to it: gacutil -l > c:\temp\gac.txt

Comment: I know it is too much to eyeball.  Was really getting a headache.
Was running gacutil from gac directory and not getting output. I shut my laptop shut down in the meanwhile. Will try again when I get home. Thanks. Happy new year.

Comment: yeah, strongly named assembles are only allowed in that directory, so that would make sense, run it again with the path specified like I showed before and you should be ok

Comment: Thank you for your help! The 3rd party controls are in the gac.